# Proving two lines through the circumcircle are parallel.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm having trouble solving the following geometry problem and would appreciate any help. I ended up proving some other two lines were parallel instead of the desired ones. Please feel free to change the title to a more descriptive one, as I didn't know how to word such a problem. Thank you.

---

Let $P$ be the point on the circumcircle of $\triangle{ABC}$ such that the perpendicular from this point to $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ is also tangent to the circle. Draw the perpendicular to $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ through $P$ and label the intersection point $Z$ as shown. Prove that $\overleftrightarrow{AP}\parallel\overleftrightarrow{ZX}$.
[image]

---

> Attempt:
>
> [image: 1]]

---

Comment: Maybe add the line through PO, and label the intersection with AB by D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that quadrilateral $XBZP$ is cyclic as $\angle BZP + \angle BXP = 180^\circ$. Then $\angle BZX = \angle BPX$, and $\angle BPX = \angle BAP$ by the Inscribed Angle Theorem(the limiting case).

Thus, as $\angle BZX = \angle BAP$, 
$$\overline{AP} \parallel \overline{ZX}$$.

Comment: Thank you SO much. We're covering simpson lines and I thought the solution had something do to with them but this is so simple. +1 for me

Answer (score 1):

Another proof. Note again that quadrilateral $XBZP$ is cyclic. Therefore $\angle ZXB = \angle ZPB$. Now draw line $\overline{PO}$ and let $D = \overline{AB} \cap \overline{PO}$. The circumcenter and orthocenter are *isogonal conjugates*, therefore $\angle APD = \angle ZPB$. Including the fact that $\overline{PD} \parallel \overline{XB}$, it follows that
$$\overline{AP} \parallel \overline{ZX}$$
.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the isogonal conjugates, would you mind explaining?